# c++ how to properly call deallocate within custom container

Tags: c++, containers, allocator

I created a custom container class that looks like this:

```
template <typename T, typename Alloc=std::allocator<T>>
class container {
    ...
};
```

To allocate memory i use `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::allocate(some_size)`.
I guess I could also just use `Alloc::allocate(some_size)`.
The problem comes when I want to deallocate the memory with `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::deallocate(...)` or `Alloc::deallocate(...)`, because `deallocate` called with `std::allocator_traits` is not static and requires an allocator object to be passed.
`Alloc::deallocate` would work because its static.
Whats the difference between those two types of calling the functions of an allocator and why is `std::alloctor_traits<Alloc>::deallocate(...)` not static anymore?

A little bit of my real code:

```
template <typename T, typename Alloc>
ring<T, Alloc>::~ring() {
    if (__n_items > 0) {
        for(reference item : *this) {
            item.~value_type();
        }
        std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::deallocate(__buffer, __size);
    }
}
```

Throwing too few arguments cause of the missing allocator instance.

Answer (score 3):

Both the `allocate` and `deallocate` methods of `allocator_traits` require an allocator object. Standard library containers are given an allocator instance to store and use (ordinarily users rely on the default constructor behavior, which default-constructs such an allocator). If you expect to use your container class with a stateful allocator, you should do the same; if your custom allocator has no per-instance state, you can just default-construct one as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much, i missed that part on std::containers :)